# Magento - Partial Refund Issue

Tags: magento

I am unable to issue partial refund through the credit memo in Magento Admin. I need to refund only a cost, and no items, so I am changing the quantity for all items to 0 and updating quantities, so no items are being refunded.  Next I put in the amount I want to refund in Adjustment Refund and either get an error that it must be a positive amount (I put 0.55) or that the max I can refund is what the order total was.  I tried using Adjustment Fee, but it marked all items as refunded, despite them being removed...

Any thoughts?  Every thread I've seen about this has no solutions.

I am using Magento Community 1.7.0.2

Comment: "I tried using Adjustment Fee, but it marked all items as refunded, despite them being removed" - Did you hit the update QTY button after setting their quantities to 0 on the credit memo?

Comment: I did.  When I do the adjustment refund after setting all the bundle products to 0 and clicking the update QTY (the list of order items then goes away) and click the refund button, I get the "Maximum amount available to refund is" error and the list of products that I just zeroed out comes back...I'm thinking there's a bug for bundle products?  It seems to ignore what I've zeroed out and then tries to add the adjustment refund, therefor having a higher refund total than order total.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am facing the same exact issue. Partial refunds not working for bundled products.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter to allow partial refunds is actually set by the payment method used to place the order.

Some payment methods do not allow partial refunds, however you can make a quick edit to the payment method's model to allow partial refunds.

1. Determine what payment method was used.
2. Find the payment method's model in the `app/code` directory.

   - If it's a Magento core payment method, it will be located under
     `app/code/core/[PaymentMethodName]/Model/[PaymentMethodModelName]`
   - If it's a 3rd party payment extension, the model will be located under:
     `app/code/[local or community]/[PaymentMethodName]/Model/[PaymentMethodModelName]`
3. Once you have found the correct model file for the payment method, open it and look for:
   `protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial = false;`
4. Change it to true, like this:
   `protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial = true;`
5. Save the file, and try doing a partial refund on your order.

If you cannot find `protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial = false;`, try adding it at the top of the model class.

If done correctly, you will now be able to do partial refunds on orders using this payment method.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Axel.  I tried messing around a bit with different products and it doesn't work only for bundle products. A simple product with the same payment method did work.  I am using bundle products because my products can be configured, but also need to pull stock from inventory.  I have not seen any documentation about refund restrictions with bundle products.  Any ideas?